# 2GP: Filtered report charts in Lightning Record Pages can't be packaged and working

Tags: lightning-experience, managed-package, report-chart, 2gp

In a 2nd generation managed Package, I want to include Filtered report charts in Lightning Record Pages, but I either can't package them because the filter is namespaced, or the filter is broken in the subscriber org because the namespace is missing.

Does anybody know a workaroud? Or if it is documented behavior?

Error message when packaging with namespace:

`Account_Special_Datensatzseite: Component [flexipage:reportChart] attribute [reportFilter]: Unknown Filter: namespace__fieldname__c.namespace__Account__c.Id`

How to reproduce:

1. Create a project with namespace in dx
2. Create a scratch org with this namespace
3. Create a report on Opportunities and include the account information so you can filter on this
4. Add this report to the Account Lightning Record Page
5. Pull the metadata with dx
6. Create a new package (2GP)
7. Create a new package version -> this will fail
8. Remove the namespacing from the flexipage:reportChart component in the metadata of the Lightning Record Page
9. Create a new package version -> this will be successful
10. Install the package to another org (without the previous namespace)
11. Go to the Account and Activate the Lightning Record Page from the package
12. You will get the following error
    [image: You can't view chart data because either the chart is filtered by a field you can't access or the field has been removed from the chart's report type.]

Comment: I don't have an answer but I'm interested because I'm a managed package release engineer at Salesforce.org. If you could add a few more details I'd be happy to try to find someone to ask internally.

Comment: (e.g., have you tried it in 1GP and know if the behavior is the same? can you include a step-by-step summary of behavior with and without the namespace, including exactly when it fails, and a sample of metadata?)

Comment: I haven't tried 1gp yet and I hope I don't have to...

Comment: @DavidReed Does this help to clarify the issue?

Comment: Yes, very much - thank you. I have one product I work on that appears to show that this _works_ in 1GP. I'll see if I can identify the right person to bring this to their attention - cannot promise any fast insight, however.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue now for 6 months and today I decided I can't solve it alone... if I get any insight I will comment on this post. The differences between 1GP and 2GP are really annoying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114019/discussion-between-david-reed-and-nina-rosen).

Comment: Same issue here on custom objects. No help from Salesforce Partner Support either. Any updates @DavidReed? I don't have access to chat.

Comment: @ChrisKarpyszyn (or Nina) can either of you share a minimal reproduction in a GitHub repository? That would be something I could share easily to document the problem.

Comment: @DavidReed there is now a video on how to reproduce the Error, the repo wouldn't work because of the namespace:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344071/2gp-filtered-report-charts-in-lightning-record-pages-cant-be-packaged-error-w