# 2GP: Filtered report charts in Lightning Record Pages can't be packaged (Error with flexipage unknown)

Tags: lightning-experience, managed-package, report-chart, 2gp

I am facing an Error when trying to package a Lightning Record Page via 2GP but I am not able to push it.
The following Error is printed in the Terminal:

> Account_Record_Page.flexipage-meta.xml Component[flexipage:reportChart] attribute [reportFilter]: Unbekannt err Filter: neo_prm__ErrorObj__c.neo_prm__Account__c.Id

How to reproduce:

1. Create a project with namespace in dx
2. Create a scratch org with this namespace
3. Create a report on Opportunities and include the account information so you can filter on this
4. Add this report to the Account Lightning Record Page
5. Pull the metadata with dx
6. Create a new package (2GP)
7. Create a new package version -> this will fail

Is there someone having a similar problem and can maybe provide a workaround? I am grateful for any help.
I also recorded a short video where I captured the steps to reproduce this Error.

https://youtu.be/qpWpsjBsVO0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What metadata do you see pulled at step 5? Have you looked in the flexipage XML to see what is being complained about? Could it be some separate metadata element that hasn't been included in your package directory?

Comment: The error message seems to suggest you are using a namespace of "neo_prm". Is that the one you create in step 1? Is the namespace linked to your Dev Hub? I also note that the first part of the error doesn't have "__" after the namespace prefix - is that a typo from when you wrote the question, or is the error really like that?

Comment: Are you using standard report type or custom report type?

Comment: Previously noted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322217/2gp-filtered-report-charts-in-lightning-record-pages-cant-be-packaged-and-work). Have you filed a support Case?

Comment: I uploaded the video that reproduces the error. I think that way it is a bit easier to explain the issue. I created a Custom Object with a lookup Relationship to a standard Object and after that I added a custom Report Type

Comment: _Please_ open a Case! linking them to an underlying issue helps document impact and priority. (I am a Salesforce employee and can also share this post and the earlier related one internally but a Case is a helpful locus to get triaging going).